# How to return an object of any type

Tags: java

Can someone help me how to return and capture any variable type?

```
public static Object returnVal()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Object obj=new Object();
    System.out.println(obj.returnVal().getClass().getName); //or something which should print String
}
```

Here i want to capture what type of variable it is returning, and print that value.

It could be String, integer or any Object also. Can someone help me in this regard.

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Then you need to invoke `returnVal` to get your `Object`; something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Object obj = returnVal();
    System.out.println(obj.getClass().getName());
}
```

which outputs `java.lang.String` if you want *just* `String` you can use

```
System.out.println(obj.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

Comment: How to get the value? obj.toString()? What if it returns an integer or dobule or object itself?

Comment: If you're going to program to `Object`, then yes; `obj.toString()` will work for any `Object` type. It's your program, try it and see.